# Rodzadra's Geolocation Error (Yii2 Extension)

Tags: php, yii2, geolocation, extension-methods

[image]

That's error i got. I've added rodzadra's component in web.php. What should i do to fix it?
thanks.

EDIT !!!!
After I added the extension path in autoload_psr4.php, I got new error that mention for Geolocation line 78 (`$urlTmp = preg_replace('!\{\{(accepted_formats)\}\}!', self::$return_formats, self::$provider['plugin_url']);`).

The Error said :

```
Illegal string offset 'plugin_url'
```

Here's my Geolocation.php

```
<?php


/**
 * @link https://github.com/rodzadra/yii2-geolocation
 * @version 0.0.2
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2015 rodzadra
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0 GPL
 */

namespace rodzadra\geolocation;

use yii;
use yii\base\Component;


class Geolocation extends Component{

    /**
     *
     * @author rodzadra
     * @package rodzadra\yii2-geolocation
     */

    public $config = ['provider'=>NULL,'return_formats'=>NULL, 'api_key'=>NULL];

    private static $plugins         = array();
    private static $provider        = 'geolocation';
    private static $return_formats   = 'php';
    private static $api_key         = NULL;


    public function __construct($config = array()) {

        self::$plugins = array_diff(scandir((__DIR__).'/plugins/'), array('..', '.'));

        if (isset($config['config']['provider'])) {

            $provider = $config['config']['provider'];

            if (in_array($provider . ".php", self::$plugins)) {

                require (__DIR__) . '/plugins/' . $provider . '.php';

                if (isset($config['config']['return_formats'])) {
                    $format = $config['config']['return_formats'];

                    if(in_array($format, $plugin['accepted_formats'])){
                        self::$return_formats = $format;
                    } else {
                        self::$return_formats = $plugin['default_accepted_format'];
                    }
                }

                self::$provider = $plugin;

                self::$api_key = (isset($config['config']['api_key']))?$config['config']['api_key']:NULL;

            } else {
                throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'The requested Item could not be found.');
            }
        } else {
            require (__DIR__) . '/plugins/geoplugin.php';
            self::$provider = $plugin;
            self::$return_formats = $plugin['default_accepted_format'];
        }

        return parent::__construct($config);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the plugin URL
     *
     * @param strint $ip
     * @return string
     */
    private static function createUrl($ip){
        $urlTmp = preg_replace('!\{\{(accepted_formats)\}\}!', self::$return_formats, self::$provider['plugin_url']);
        $urlTmp = preg_replace('!\{\{(ip)\}\}!', $ip, $urlTmp);

        if(isset(self::$api_key))
            $urlTmp = preg_replace('!\{\{(api_key)\}\}!', self::$api_key, $urlTmp);

        return $urlTmp;
    }

    /**
     * Returns client info
     *
     * @param string $ip You can supply an IP address or none to use the current client IP address
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getInfo($ip=NULL){

        if(!isset($ip))
            $ip = self::getIP ();

        $url = self::createUrl($ip);

        //print_r($url); exit;

        if(self::$return_formats == 'php')
            return unserialize(file_get_contents($url));
        else
            return file_get_contents($url);
    }


    /**
     *
     * Changes the used plugin
     *
     * @param string $provider The provider plugin name
     * @param string $format The data return format
     */
    public static function getPlugin($provider=NULL, $format=NULL, $api_key=NULL){

        self::$plugins = array_diff(scandir((__DIR__).'/plugins/'), array('..', '.'));

        if(isset($api_key)){
            self::$api_key = $api_key;
        }


        if (in_array($provider . ".php", self::$plugins)) {

            require (__DIR__) . '/plugins/' . $provider . '.php';

            if(in_array($format, $plugin['accepted_formats'])){
                self::$return_formats = $format;
            } else {
                self::$return_formats = $plugin['default_accepted_format'];
            }

            self::$provider = $plugin;
        }

    }

    private static function getIP(){
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
        getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
        getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
        getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
        getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
        getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        return $ip;
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you added this to composer.json and updated by `composer update`?

Comment: @Yupik, I have added to composer.json but i just copy the source from github rodzadra's to my vendor folder. Because i always get failed when i installed this extension using composer

Comment: And that's your problem. Never add manually something to `/vendor`, because it won't be autoloaded.

Comment: what is the folder structure and where you added it

Comment: @KandarpPatel , What folder structure did you mean? i added the rodzadra's folder extension inside vendor.

Comment: @Yupik , Is there other solution to instal the extension without composer? because i always get error when installing rodzadra's extension

Comment: You can add path to this extension in `/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`, but seriously, you shouldn't do that. Better try to fix this composer installation error.

Comment: @Adinda yes the folder structure of the extension .. ie. path of the Geolocation.php file in the extension ..

Comment: @Yupik, I have added path on  /vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php but I get new error "Illegal string offset 'plugin_url'" . Please kindly see in my editted question.

Answer (score 0):

```
"rodzadra\\geolocation\\" => array($vendorDir . '/path-to-the-extension-files')
```

add this in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php

whenever you add extensions manually you need to give the path in autoloader

But composer is always recommended

Comment: I already did that, after that i got a new error. Please Check it in my editted post